# 'confluent local services start' return a not a directory error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use confluent CLI for the first time. I've successfully installed it and I can run the confluent command. But when I try to start confluent with the command `confluent local services start` I have this error:

[image]

Obviously there is a bad configuration issue with the path to the zookeeper.properties but I can't find how this path is built. It seems that it takes my CONFLUENT_HOME variable and add  "etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties" to it but I don't understand why.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your host OS? If you have Docker, I'd suggest just using that

Comment: I'm on windows and doing in this inside a docker container

Comment: Its documented that `confluent` doesn't work on windows. Unclear what container you're using. Assuming basic Ubuntu, then there'd be no Kafka/Zookeeper to run... but you should not be running that inside a container, either. Just use the [`all-in-one` Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one) to run _separate containers_ rather than all services _in one container_ (not recommended anyway by Docker best-practices)